# Averaging indices of table using pandas and numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have been playing with pandas for a few hours now, I was wondering whether there is another faster way to add an extra column to your table which consists of the average of that row? I am creating a new list which contains the mean and then I am incorporating it in the data frame.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
userdata={"A":[2,5],"B":[4,6]}
tab=pd.DataFrame((userdata), columns=["A","B"])
lst=[np.mean([tab.loc[i,"A"],tab.loc[i,"B"]]) for i in range(len(tab.index))]
tab["Average of A and B"]=pd.DataFrame(lst)
tab
```

Answer (score 3):

try `df.mean(1)` with `assign`.  `df.mean(1)` tells pandas to calculate the mean along `axis=1` (rows).  `axis=0` is the default.

```
df.assign(Mean=df.mean(1))
```

This produces a copy of `df` with added column.

To alter the existing dataframe

```
df['Mean'] = df.mean(1)
```

---

***demo***

```
tab.assign(Mean=tab.mean(1))

   A  B  Mean
0  2  4   3.0
1  5  6   5.5
```

Answer (score 2):

A NumPy solution would be to work with the underlying array data for performance -

```
tab['average'] = tab.values.mean(1)
```

To choose specific columns, like `'A'` and `'B'` -

```
tab['average'] = tab[['A','B']].values.mean(1)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [41]: tab = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(10000,10)))

# @piRSquared's soln
In [42]: %timeit tab.assign(Mean=tab.mean(1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 615 µs per loop

In [43]: tab = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(10000,10)))

In [44]: %timeit tab['average'] = tab.values.mean(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 297 µs per loop


In [37]: tab = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(10000,100)))

# @piRSquared's soln
In [38]: %timeit tab.assign(Mean=tab.mean(1))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.71 ms per loop

In [39]: tab = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(10000,100)))

In [40]: %timeit tab['average'] = tab.values.mean(1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.6 ms per loop
```